# Is there a nicer solution for (not) continuing after try catch in a method?

Tags: java, methods, try-catch

Right now my solution looks like this:

```
public void method() {
  int number;
  boolean continue = true; 
  try {
     number = parseInt(this.something);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     //some code
     continue = false;
  }

  if (continue) {
    //more code
  }
}
```

Is there something prettier out there?

Comment: using `return`?

Comment: Isn't `continue` a reserved word in Java BTW?

Comment: Based on this code sample alone, however, it seems a bit like you're asking the wrong question. If you had validated `this.something` to be an integer early on, you wouldn't have this problem in the first place. Most times, you want to fail early and loud so that you don't introduce unnecessary complexity in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a nicer solution for (not) continuing after try catch in a method?

The intended way is to write the code that should be skipped inside the try block:

```
public void method() {
  try {
     int number;
     number = parseInt(this.something);
    //more code
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // log exception
    // do things to recover from the error if possible
    // maybe rethrow `e` or throw another exception
  }
  // avoid to write some code here, usually it is wrong.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though it is a `void` method, you can use `return;` which then will exit the method. Therefore a perfectly fine solution to your "problem" is to just use `return` and removing the `if` as follows:

```
public void method() {
    int number;
    try {
        number = parseInt(this.something);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //some code
        return;
    }
    //more code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object is not setup properly (this.something was not set), it might be better to throw then catch in the calling code.  If you just return, the caller might assume the method completed successfully.  Otherwise the code provided by Aidin would work.

Comment: The `//some code` could still assign appropriate values, leaving the object's fields is a good state. But definitely something to watch out for.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply ignore the exception and log the exception for information purpose:

```
public void method() {

    int number;

    try {
        number = parseInt(this.something);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        // here could be some System.out.println or a logging API
    }
}
```

But if you have a return, just return null and evaluate your result whether is null or not.

```
public Integer method() {

    try {
        return parseInt(this.something);
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
        // here could be some System.out.println or a logging API
    }

    return null;
}

Integer number = method();
if (number != null) {....
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use retun; break; or possibly System.exit()

Comment: Can't use `break` there, and using `System.exit()` is really bad, since caller of `method()` might want to do other stuff.